# Get element id number and append it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, parseint

Good day.

I'm trying to use use jQuery to extract serial number out of link id and append it using jQuery.

```
<a class="links" id="link_*serial number goes here*" href="google.com"> Google.com </a>
```

and the script goes like this

```
    $('.links').append('<div>
<label> Check this box to remove this link:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="delete_link_id'.parseInt($(this).attr("id"));.'></input></div>');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Um, **do not** append a label and input inside an anchor!  Are you sure you don't want `.after()` instead of `.append()`?

Comment: That seems to be recurring suggestion, may I ask why is it so bad to use append in this case?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, placing a `label`/`input` inside an `a` tag is invalid in all current versions of html.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var linkSerial = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
```

Also, in your code you're appending to an anchor...I don't think this is what you want...

Comment: Just one thing, when there are more then 1 link, using $(this) will result in "undefined" any ideas?

Comment: More than 1 link shouldn't matter...I'm a bit confused. `this` will reference the current element.

Answer (score 1):

tymeJV's answer is good *if your serial number does not contain any underscores*.  If it does not, please upvote and accept his answer.

However, if there might be a possibility that the serial number could contain underscores, you are better off simply replacing 'link_' with an empty string:

```
var linkSerial = this.id.replace('link_', '');
```

Then insert `linkSerial` wherever you need the serial number, such as:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="delete_link_id' + linkSerial + '"/>'
```

BTW, there are a few other issues with your code:

1. The concatenation operator in JavaScript is `+` not `.`
2. It's invalid to place a `label`/`input` inside an anchor (`a`) tag.
3. The `input` tag is self-closing, so `</input>` is invalid.

Comment: I didn't knew it was invalid to use it inside <a> tag. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also this way

```
  $(".links").prop("id").replace(/\D/g, '')
```

Comment: I do believe that "split()" is faster then RegEX tho!

Comment: Yeah, but regex gives flexibility, i don't know how the serialnumber will be masked, and he can later play with the regex to extract the numbers

Comment: You're right about that, but from what i understand by the way he's coding, this is always going to be link_[id].  Else he should have used the ".data()" method another attribute such as data-id="[id]", or at least i would have done that ;P